# Close a survey in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

How do i close a survey in SharePoint so that people can no longer respond?  i do not want to delte it.  I can not change permissions as they are tied to other items in the SharePoint.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by you  cannot change permissions because they are tied to other items? You can set permissions just for the survey if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the survey list to no longer inherit permissions from the site. You find that in List Settings > Permissions. Don't copy the permissions, it will make your life easier. If you do end up copying them, just remove all the permissions from the list.

[image]

Then you can give read only access to the groups on this list. That way the permissions do not change for any other list or library, only for this survey.